# Is it possible to animate a CSS variable using jquery?

Tags: jquery, css

I'm new to Web development and javascript. At the moment, I've got a page with a button on it, and when it is pressed, it changes the value of one of my css variables. The result of pushing the button is that certain parts of the page instantaneously change colour. I wanted to alter this behaviour so that the change in colour is gradual. But I can't seem to get it to work. My code is below:

HTML

```
<div id="background">
  <div id="quote-box">
    <div id="text-wrapper">
      <p id="text" class="cutout-text">I think, therefore I am.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="author-wrapper">
      <p id="author" class="cutout-text">- Rene Descartes</p>
    </div>
    <div id="buttons-wrapper">
      <a href=# id="tweet-quote">
        <div class="icon cutout-bg">
          <i class="fa fa-twitter remains"></i>
        </div>
      </a>
      <div id="buttons-spacer"></div>
      <div id="new-quote" class="button cutout-bg">
        <p class=".remains">New Quote</p>
      </div>
    </d>
  </div>
</div>
```

SCSS

```
:root {
  --bg-colour: blue;
  --box-colour: white;
  --box-height: 250px;
  --box-width: 500px;
  --button-height: 3em;
}

@mixin center-content {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

*:link {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#background {
  @include center-content;
  background-color: var(--bg-colour);
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

#quote-box {
  background-color: var(--box-colour);
  border-radius: 2%;
  height: var(--box-height);
  padding: 50px;
  width: var(--box-width);
}

.cutout-text {
  color: var(--bg-colour);
}

.cutout-bg {
  background-color: var(--bg-colour);
}

.remains {
  color: var(--box-colour);
  font-size: 1.6em;
  padding: 5px;
}

#text-wrapper {
  font-size: 2em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  width: var(--box-width);
}

#author-wrapper {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  margin-bottom: 3.6em;
  text-align: right;
  width: var(--box-width);
}

#buttons-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: var(--box-width)
}

#buttons-spacer {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.icon {
  @include center-content;
  border-radius: 10%;
  height: var(--button-height);
  width: var(--button-height);
}

.button {
  @include center-content;
  border-radius: 7%;
  color: var(--box-colour);
  height: var(--button-height);
  width: calc(var(--button-height) * 3);
}

.button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

JQUERY

```
 const QUOTES = [
    "Veni, vidi, vici",
    "I think, therefore there I am."
  ];
  
 const COLOURS = [
    "orange",
    "blue",
    "red",
    "purple"
  ];

function randomColour() {
  return COLOURS[Math.floor(Math.random() * COLOURS.length)];
}

function randomQuote() {
  return QUOTES[Math.floor(Math.random() * QUOTES.length)];
}

function randomState() {
  var colour = randomColour();
  var quote = randomQuote();
  var author =  "Random Quote Machine";
  return {
    colour: colour, quote: quote, author: author}
}

function initialView() {
  let state = randomState();
  $(":root").css('--bg-colour', state.colour);
  $("#text").text(state.quote);
  $("#author").text(state.author);
}

function nextView() {
  let state = randomState();
  $(":root").animate({'--bg-colour': state.colour}, "slow");
}


function respondToButton() {
  $(".button").on("click", nextView)
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  initialView();
  respondToButton();
});
```

The jquery function `initialView()` works as expected, it styles the page according to the values stored in `state`. The page updates instantaneously.

The alternative function `nextView()` is the function I'm having trouble with. I expected that when I click on a `.button` element, the CSS variable `--bg-colour` would begin animating, which would be portrayed as the background of the page changing colour gradually. In reality, nothing happens when I click the button. However, The function `respondToButton()` definately works, which can be verified by switching `nextView` to `initialView`. Then, when the button is pressed, the background instantly changes colour.

What can I do to fix `nextView()` so it does what I intended?

Comment: You can just use CSS transition for the background color property.

Comment: There are better ways to do this type of animation, but to answer your question as to how you were trying to achieve it, you can't target CSS text like regular HTML elements on the DOM. For that, you need to use the CSSOM -- see the reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS_Object_Model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this

> All animated properties should be animated to a single numeric value, except as noted below; most properties that are non-numeric cannot be animated using basic jQuery functionality (For example, width, height, or left can be animated but background-color cannot be, unless the jQuery.Color plugin is used)

on the following site: https://api.jquery.com/animate/. It seems it is a jQuery problem so you could use a plugin, or use css since the `background-colour`proprty can be animated. Just do something like

```
/* css */
#background, .cutout-text, .cutout-bg {
  transition: background-color 400ms linear;
}

/* jQuery */

function nextView() {
  let state = randomState();
  $(":root").css('--bg-colour', state.colour);
}
```